# How to select an element from a drop down unordered list in Selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, testing, selenium-ide

I'm having trouble selecting a link from this dropdown menu. The html is this:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22594"><a href="http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/" data-level="2"><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Automation Practice Form</span></span></a></li>
```

I've tried

Command: Select
Target: class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22594"

But it's failing. I would like to navigate to the link to test other things on that webpage.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Select class, use normal way of identifying the element. You can use xpath : `//span[text()='Automation Practice Form']` to identify element and then click on it. It should work.

**Note:** We should use Select class when it is present in DOM

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with text as **Automation Practice Form** you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//a[@href='http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/']/span[@class='menu-item-text']/span[@class='menu-text']
```